# Method push is not adding a value to a vector that previously had the same value

Tags: javascript

The goal of the code I'm going to present is to create a aux vector that will contain petri nets transitions, arcs and places. I'm dividing a petri net into several groups, each group is a transition with respective input arcs and places.

The issue is the following: After I put the info in the first position of the aux vector, I'm unable to put a place with the same id of the place of the previous group. For example, if I have a transition with place_id=1 and place_id=2, and the next transition have place_id=2 and place_id=3, the code doesn't write the value place_i=2 in the vector for the second group.

```
function conflict() {
    var id = [];
    var source = [];
    var target = [];
    var aux = [];
    var cont = [];
    var places = pnml.getElementsByTagName("place");
    var arcs = pnml.getElementsByTagName("arc");
    var transitions = pnml.getElementsByTagName("transition");

    for (var i = 0; i < transitions.length; i++) {
        target.push(transitions[i].getAttribute("id"));
        aux.push([]);
        for (var j = 0; j < arcs.length; j++) {
            if (arcs[j].getAttribute("target") == transitions[i].getAttribute("id")) {
                id.push(arcs[j].getAttribute("id"));
                source.push(arcs[j].getAttribute("source"));
                //console.log(arcs[j].getAttribute( "source" ));
            }
        }
        //console.log(id); 
        //console.log(arcs);
        //console.log(places);
        aux[i].push(id, source, target);
        //id.length=0;
        target = [];
        source = [];
        id = [];
    }
}
```

[Image of the platform with console open](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/24/a8eb526aea80f6bb8370c4802e8582a6-full.png)
Thanks in advance

Comment: It would help a lot if you would build a snippet including a sample of your HTML, and also explain what exactly it is about the results that are incorrect.

Comment: Hi, I don't have html. The code I presented is added to a code that belongs to a platform (IOPT-Tools). Unfortunatly, I cant add images, because I don't have sufficient reputation. The image would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing a whole lot for the issue, try to change this

```
aux.push([]);
```

to this

```
aux[i]=[];
```

So that you initialize and fill using an index instead of a push and an index later, for consistency. 
Let me know if it helps

EDIT: 
Also this

```
aux[i].push(id, source, target);
```

to this (maybe? )

```
aux[i].push({ id: id, source:source, target:target});
```

You probably want to keep objects in aux, so you need to push an object, not 3 parameters like that

Comment: Was about to type essentially the same thing. "Don't know what you're doing... but you're not creating an array for each iteration". But I was thinking, why is `aux[i]` an array if you're only pushing one thing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem persists. I added a link with the image of the platform and the open console. As you can see, the second group only has place_id=11 and should also contain place_id=3. It seems the push doesn't accept the same value, as the value I pushed before for the previously group.

Comment: Well, push will just push stuff, wont ask questions. You can push the same thing over and over, its not like it requires "unique" objects/values. Without at least a set of objects to test it quickly i dont think i can help any more... If you can, create a fiddle, without even html, just test objects, so that we can run the sample. Would make helping you much much easier

Comment: MKougiouris thank you very much! Now the values are all there! Could you please explain why in the way I did it doesn't work? Once again thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably the way you used `push` originaly.
You where pushing `.push(id,source,target)`, but push only accepts 1 argument.
You where supposed to create a new object `{id:id, source:source,target:target}` and push that instead, so that you will capture those 3 variables together

Comment: I did google "petri net" for this... we learn something new every day!